# Microsoft excel - After saving file size decrease

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to read excel file in c# however it gives me '**External table is not in the expected format.**' error.
Below is my sample code

```
string con =@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + reportname + @".xls;" +
                      @"Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from ["+reportname+"$]", connection);
                using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {...
                     ...
            }}}
```

The strange this is when I try to open the excel manually and save it back, it gives me a pop-up saying '**The report.xls may contain features that are not compatible with web page.Do you want to keep the workbook in this format?**' If i select yes the file size reduce from 2.5MB to 10KB.
Now if I run my code, it also works fine.

What should be done in this scenario, as I cannot keep saving the file manually to make it work?

Comment: I'll bet that if you check your "Excel file" with a **text** editor you'll find an HTML page with a table. That's a dirty hack performed by many sites to *fake* Excel export instead of generating a real `xlsx` file. That's mostly due to ignorance - `xlsx` is a compressed XML file, doesn't require Excel on the server, and there are a *lot* of libraries for it.

Comment: Either ask the file's author to create a real xlsx file, or parse the HTML table using eg HtmlAgility and export the data to an Excel file, using a library like EPPlus. EPPlus doesn't require OLEDB or Excel on the server and can generate an Excel file from a DataTable or generic collection with only a couple of lines.